# Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\ibsof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe manage.py runserver'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use runserver command over pycharm code terminal. But now it is giving me the error. " Unable to create process using Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\ibsof\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe manage.py runserver'
. But I have the python interpreter in my environment path. Also, I have my virtual environment which I created while initiating the project but still and using the interpreter in my environment I was getting the same error..

Comment: it seems you didn't activate your virtual env yet, did you?

Comment: how activate  i don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Uninstall PyCharm completely and reinstalled it.
2. Re-install the latest version of python via python.org
3. Restart your system
4. Ensure python path is added to your environment variable and test using command prompt("C:>python" should bring out the python version)
5. Open your IDE (PyCharm in my case) and re-open your project folder
6. Open A NEW VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT and activate it
7. Re-install your dependencies ("pip install -r requirements.txt") and runserver

I actually THINK that steps 6 and 7 above is all you need, but I am just detailing what I did to make mine work.